# Can ExactTarget and AMPscript use a form to upload an image?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, form

We have many forms within our AMPscript powered microsite landing pages to edit and define content within pages. Am curious to know if there are known techniques that would add a browse button and the ability to upload an image (or several images) via the form process into the portfolio (or elsewhere). If so is it a named function or what other technologies might provide that ability (SOAP or REST?) Currently we load images into the "Portfolio" and use a text field on the form to link records to those images in web pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in AMPscript using the [AMPscript API methods](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) or in SOAP.  You need to use the [Portfolio object](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/portfolio/) in either case.

Comment: Good then to know it can be done. Reviewing the links suggests to me that there are more pre-requisites to be considered before I will be able to make use of the API functions. If you have other suggested links on where to learn about the API's and what needs to be considered for a "Browse -> File Upload" method I'd love to know more. Thank you Tim.